# How to filter a Line Chart with a Measure in Power BI?

Tags: database, powerbi, relational-database, dax, powerbi-desktop

I currently have a table in Power BI named `Fruit`.

Here is sample data from `Fruit`:

| Issue id | Label | Label 1 | Label 2 | Label 3 | Label 4 | Created | Resolved | Time Difference (MINS) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1000 | Apples | Grapes | Bananas | Oranges | Strawberries | 14/03/2021 11:38:23 | 11/02/2022 | 525632 |
| 1001 | Oranges | Pears | Apples | Bananas | Strawberries | 13/03/2021 12:34:34 | 18/03/2022 11:38:23 | 524324 |
| 1002 | Pears | Dragon Fruit | Apples | Strawberries | Dragon Fruit | 04/03/2021 18:31:11 | 12/03/2022 11:38:23 | 525345 |
| 1003 | Bananas | Oranges | Apples | Grapes | Pears | 11/03/2021 19:34:57 | 11/03/2022 11:38:23 | 528264 |
| 1004 | Grapes | Apples | Bananas | Pears | Strawberries | 12/03/2021 12:32:52 | 15/03/2022 11:38:23 | 521927 |

I have created a table to join the label values into one:
`AllLabel = SUMMARIZE(UNION(VALUES(Fruit[Label 1]), VALUES(Fruit[Label 2]), VALUES(Fruit[Label 3]), VALUES(Fruit[Label 4])),Fruit[Label 1])`

I also have created a measure count the labels and filter them uniquely:
`Apples`
`Oranges`
`Pears`
`Bananas`
`Strawberries`
`Dragon Fruit`
`Grapes`:

```
SELECTEDFruit = 
var _selectedFruit = SELECTEDVALUE(AllLabel[Label 1])
return
CALCULATE(COUNTROWS(Fruit) , FILTER(Fruit,Fruit[Label 1] = _selectedFruit || Fruit[Label 2] = _selectedFruit || Fruit[Label 3] = _selectedFruit || Fruit[Label 4] = _selectedFruit))
```

This is how the tables look:

[image]

I have a line chart to calculate the Average resolution time:
[image]
[image]

However, when I choose a particular fruit using a slicer, it does not change the value of Average Resolution Time Line Chart.
[image]

How can I filter the Average Resolution Line Chart using the Label 1 slicer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the reason is that your tables don't have relationships. make sure that there exist relationships between tables. it can be one active relationship between two table,you should use dax Relationship functions such as USERELATIONSHIP formula for calculate between other columns.
however i recommend using pivot,unpivot and union dax function like in order to create another table to get best result from slicer and there will be no need for your dax formula AllLabel

```
UnpivotedTable= FILTER(
UNION(
SELECTCOLUMNS('Fruit',"Created",[Created],"Resolved",[Resolved],"Time Difference (MINS)",[Time Difference (MINS)],"label",[Label]),
SELECTCOLUMNS('Fruit',"Created",[Created],"Resolved",[Resolved],"Time Difference (MINS)",[Time Difference (MINS)],"label",[Label 1]),
SELECTCOLUMNS('Fruit',"Created",[Created],"Resolved",[Resolved],"Time Difference (MINS)",[Time Difference (MINS)],"label",[Label 2]),
SELECTCOLUMNS('Fruit',"Created",[Created],"Resolved",[Resolved],"Time Difference (MINS)",[Time Difference (MINS)],"label",[Label 3]),
SELECTCOLUMNS('Fruit',"Created",[Created],"Resolved",[Resolved],"Time Difference (MINS)",[Time Difference (MINS)],"label",[Label 4])),[Label]<>"")
```

Comment: What type of relationship is required, and with which columns? One to one, many to many, one to many? Which directionality? I have previously tried making a relationships with no use

Comment: I have changed my reply that might help you